# How to pass a local referenced variable to a lambda function, but the function will be called when its closure is already finished?

Tags: c++

The code below should print two same integers, but that's not the case. An analogous program in JavaScript would print two same numbers.

It seems reasonable in C++, because when the `stdfun` is executed, `regfun` already finished, the `local_var` *doesn't exist anymore* at that time.

So my question is how can we correctly access the captured local variable beyond the lifetime of its context like JavaScript does per default?

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread(std::function<void()> stdfun)
{   
    int id = rand();
    std::function<void()> call = [=]()
    {
        Sleep(1000);//let regfun finish 
        stdfun();
    };
    std::async(std::launch::async,call);
    return id;
}

void regfun()
{
    int local_var = -1;
    std::function<void()> stdfun = [=,&local_var]() mutable -> void
    {
        cout<<local_var<<endl;
    };
    local_var = start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread(stdfun);
    cout<<local_var<<endl;
}

int main() 
{
    regfun();
    Sleep(1000000);
}
```

It is so hard to describe what my question really is, but I just need something in c++ like what we do in javascript.  If you are very famillar with javascript, maybe you can understand what I fully mean.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: `start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread` - dat name

Comment: @user2176127 It should be named `start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread_and_return_a_random_id`

Comment: @Gisway: Do you really find this title good? I don't like it for several reasons: the problem doesn't have anything to do with `std::function` (but with lambda) and how the lambda is executed (in a different thread; that's unimportant; the problem is only with the exited context). I tried to make this clearer with my edit.

Comment: Thanks,I know the title is not good, I tried a lot, it still doesn't mean what I really want to say. The real thing i want to say is the how to use referenced variable from out of its closure.

Comment: I don't understand this. You use it *inside* the closure (at least this is where the problem occurs). *Every* captured variable *lives outside* the closure.

Comment: If you invoke the lambda function from in the same closuer where the variable is defined, there is no any problem to use the referenced variable inside the lambda function. In this case the lambda function as a parameter is passed to a different thread, and invoke that function from this thread, so that is why I say using from outside of the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a C++ version of your code that no longer does undefined behavior.

As a happy side effect, it also exhibits the behavior you want:

```
int start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread(std::function<void()> stdfun)
{   
  int id = rand();
  // no need for this to be a type erased `std::function`:
  auto call = [=]()
  {
      Sleep(1000);//let regfun finish 
      stdfun();
  };
  std::async(std::launch::async,call);
  return id;
}

void regfun()
{
  // here we create a shared pointer to an int and store it locally:
  auto local_var = std::make_shared<int>(-1);
  // we take the shared pointer and copy it by value into our lambda:
  // note that we only type erase (turn it into a std::function) when we need to,
  // no earlier.
  auto stdfun = [local_var]() mutable -> void
  {
    cout<<*local_var<<endl;
  };
  // the move is just an optimization.  It works with or without it.
  *local_var = start_stdfun_in_a_new_thread(std::move(stdfun));
  cout<<*local_var<<endl;
}

int main() 
{
  regfun();
  Sleep(1000000);
}
```

Lifetime of data in C++ is relatively simple, barring a few corner cases<sup>1</sup>.  Variables create their data in automatic storage, and when the variable goes out of scope the data is also recycled.  Unnamed data (temporaries) exist for the length of the current statement (until the `;`), but under certain circumstances can have their lifetime extended to that of a nearby reference variable.  This, however, is not transitory: so under no circumstance do unnamed objects ever outlast the `{}` enclosed block they are created in.<sup>2</sup>

You can also create data on the free store via `new` (or via other methods, like `malloc`).  Such data has a more complicated lifetime, but generally until some code somewhere says "I am done with it" explicitly.

`std::shared_ptr` is a class used to give your data a more complicated lifetime.  You can store data created via `new` in a `std::shared_ptr`, but the more conventional way is to use `std::make_shared<`TYPE`>(` construction arguments `)` to create it (this is, under most circumstances, both safer and more efficient than the other method).

Each `std::shared_ptr` variable has a conventional lifetime, however the data it *points* to has a lifetime bounded by the last *copy* of the `shared_ptr` that points to it.  (I say *copy*, because this isn't magic: if you have to unrelated `shared_ptr` to one piece of data, they will (usually) be clueless about their common data, and both think they "own" it).

So you can create a `std::shared_ptr<int>` and pass it around by value, and the data it points to will live as long as any of the pointers do.  When the last pointer goes away, the data is cleaned up.

Which is what I did above.  The lifetime of what `local_var` points to is automatically extended to be both the body of `regfun`, *and* the lifetime of `stdfun` and copies thereof (including the copy that will live in a `std::function`).

The final technique I used profusely was the use of `auto`.  `auto` is a way of creating variables that gets it type from how the variable is *initialized*.  For lambdas, this lets you store them directly (instead of as a type-erased `std::function`), as the name of a lambda cannot be uttered.

In other cases, the right hand side already details the type involved (`std::make_shared<int>` makes the type clear), and repeating it on the left hand side fails to add much clarity, and violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle.

I use `std::function` sparingly, as `std::function` is mainly about type erasure.  Type erasure is the act of taking a type with all its details, and wrapping it up in a custom crafted box that erases all of those details and leaves a uniform run time interface.  While this is cool and all, it comes with a run time (and sometimes compile time) cost.  You should engage in type erasure (like `std::function`) sparingly: in interfaces where the implementation is hidden, when you want to treat multiple different types (such as function pointers, and multiple different lambdas) in a uniform way and store them, or when you want to use lambdas and would be annoyed by your inability to utter their name.

---

<sup>1</sup> Lifetime of data in C++ is simple, barring a few corner cases.  In those corner cases, lifetime can get extremely complex.  The most simple of these corner cases is temporary lifetime extension when bound directly to a reference.  Other fun corner cases includes the concept of "safely derived pointers" and "strict aliasing", which come into play when you mess around with the types and bits of pointers.  Other complex corner cases include `static` local variables, `static` and non-static global variables, and thread-local variables, and copy elision<sup>2.1</sup>.  The most basic advice I can give you would be to simply avoid most of these corner cases, and if you find you really really need to use them, spend a whole bunch of time reading up on the implied lifetime and the various common traps and errors that occur.  The lifetime issues are sufficiently complex that "I tried it and it worked" is not strong evidence that your code is correct -- undefined,  implementation specified, or extremely fragile behavior is ridiculously easy to trigger in all of these cases.

<sup>2</sup> This sentence is a lie.  <sup>2.1</sup>Copy elision can cause an unnamed local variable to have a lifetime far longer than the enclosing block, but only because it conceptually became other named or unnamed variables, and the copy constructor/destructors where all elided (eliminated).  However, it is a useful lie, as it helps block thinking about some really common "reference lifetime extension" misconceptions.

Comment: @leemes Footnote found, and it bred.

Answer (score 6):

Your `local_var` is bound to the *local context*, i.e. it's dead when `regfun` exits, which happens almost immediately. But your lambda captures it by reference, which means that's a **dangling reference** when executing `stdfun` later, since by then `local_var` is already dead.

So that's undefined behavior. What you would need (what JavaScript does) is *extending the lifetime* of a captured variable. But that's not the case with C++11 lambdas, as explained in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda:

> #### Dangling references
>
> If an entity is captured by reference, implicitly or explicitly, and the function call operator of the closure object is invoked after the entity's lifetime has ended, undefined behavior occurs. The C++ closures do not extend the lifetimes of the captured references.

I see two solutions:

1. One solution would be **heap allocation** of the object you want to capture, pointing to it with a `std::shared_ptr`, and capture this pointer *by value* (which will copy it into the lambda instance). The last shared pointer instance will then delete the heap allocated object for you.
2. If possible you can also define it locally **in some other context** outside which in every case outlives the lifetime of its usage. (In your simple code that would be `main`, but in the most cases you want to wait for the threads; the context which both starts and waits for the threads is most probably the correct context for this.) Then pass this to `regfun` by reference, and also capture it by reference. So even when `regfun` exits, it is still a valid reference (if it's in an outliving context).

Comment: add the easy solution: `std;:shared_ptr` captured by value?

Comment: That's what I also mentioned, but if heap allocation can be avoided, the other solution I mentioned is even better.

Comment: @Yakk I edited the answer so it becomes clearer that these are two different solutions, thanks.