# pass input arguments to std::function in lambda functions

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I have a class which has a public `std::function` member like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(std::function<void(void)> _func = NULL) : m_function(_func) { }
    std::function<void()> m_function;
};
```

I have a class `X` with a member function `SomeFunction`:

```
class X
{
public:
    void SomeFunction(const std::string & _s)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

I also have a class `A` which returns an object of type `B`, like this:

```
class A
{
private:
    X x;
public:
    B GetObjectB()
    {
        std::string local = "abc";
        return B(([&]() -> void { x->SomeFunction(local); }))
    }
};
```

I then execute

```
A a;
B b = a.GetObjectB();
b.m_function();
```

The code works fine until the function `SomeFunction` is called, and the input arguments `_s` does not have a value although have passed `local` as its input argument.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling your lambda to default capture by reference (`[&]`), and it's capturing the reference to `local` that's on the stack. As a stack variable, this is deallocated when the scope exits, so the returned object's `my_function` has captured a dangling reference. Try `[=]`.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code

```
std::string local="abc";
return B(([&]()->void{x->SomeFunction(local);}))
```

captures all used variables **by reference**, and returns the function. Among the captured variables is the **local** variable `local`, whose lifetime ends when the scope exits, i.e. when returning from the function. So the *local* variable doesn't exist anymore when the lambda will be executed later, which means that the captured reference is invalid ("dangling reference").

Quoting from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda:

> ### Dangling references
>
> If an entity is captured by reference, implicitly or explicitly, and
>   the function call operator of the closure object is invoked after the
>   entity's lifetime has ended, undefined behavior occurs. The C++
>   closures do not extend the lifetimes of the captured references.

This paragraph indicates that in other languages with closure support  (e.g. in JavaScript), the lifetime of variables captured by reference are *extended*, which is not the case in C++.

The same problem exists for the variable `x` which is a member variable of the class `A` the function was invoked on. While you probably don't have a problematic code in your test, this might become a problem, too:

```
B b;

// some other context
{
    A a;
    b = a.GetObjectB();
}

// The lambda previously returned from a.GetObjectB() is now
// stored in b. But it still refers to the now dead a.x!

b.m_function();    // BOOM!
```

An easy fix is to simply not capture all variables by reference but **by value**, so the variable gets copied into the lambda instance:

```
std::string local="abc";
return B(([=]()->void{x->SomeFunction(local);}))
```

Possible workarounds when you don't want to copy the value are discussed in my answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928847/592323.

Comment: It's doubly uncomfortable because there's also an implicit assumption that the `A` object is alive when the function is called...

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for pointing this out, I added it to my answer.